# Quando usar ADD ou COPY para copiar arquivos em um Dockerfile?

Tags: docker

A sintaxe do Dockerfile possui duas instruções para copiar arquivos: `ADD`e `COPY`. Ambos copiam arquivos para o container. Quando utilizar cada um?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A aplicação dependerá do que você está tentando transferir para o conteiner. De acordo com essa resposta no [`SOen`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24958548/1432957), a maior diferença do método `ADD` para o `COPY` é:

- Método `ADD` permite que o atributo `SRC` seja uma `URL`
- Se o arquivo informado no atributo `SRC` do método `ADD` possuir um formato de compressão reconhecido, ele será descoprimido.

Há uma documentação própria do [Docker: ADD or COPY](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#add-or-copy) onde ela informa a mesma coisa, e que é preferível o uso do método `COPY` por ser transparante.

Ou seja, se você não utilizará do recurso de transferência remota e descompressão, utilize o método `COPY`.

Comment: Complementando: a [documentação oficial](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#add-or-copy) indica que o `ADD` não é indicado para obter pacotes remotos, pois aumenta o tamanho da imagem. O indicado é obter com `RUN curl` ou similar e descompactar com `tar`ou similar, removendo o pacote original em seguida.